# ngtransclude exception if ng-show or ng-init is used in template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Whenever my directive template contains either ng-show or ng-init and ng-transclude I get the following javascript error: TypeError: undefined is not a function

**Directive**

```
app.directive('test', function () {
          return {
              //works
              template: '<div><div ><ul><li ng-repeat="item in items"><div ng-transclude></div></li></ul></div></div>',
              //does not work -- ucomment
              //template: '<div><div ng-show="true"><ul><li ng-repeat="item in items"><div ng-transclude></div></li></ul></div></div>',
              transclude:true,

              link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

              }
          }
      });
```

**Usage**
     `<div test>
      <div>{{item.id}}</div>
    </div>`

Any ideas why this might be happening and what the fix for it is?

A plunker of the problem is here.

To see it in action toggle the comments on the working and not working templates

http://plnkr.co/edit/AqyORo?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

$scope.items = [{ id: 1}, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4 }];

Tip : Dont put that data in link fn,because linking happens AFTER the template has been applied. Now it works,but maybe it can help in the future.

i dont know why would you use nh-show ,if the template is showing already? you could use it if you would have some toggle function that shows/hides template,but i think that template by default is ng-show="true" .

Thouse are just my thoughts.

Comment: I updated the plunker with your suggestion and still no dice.